# infragistics winforms controls don't scale

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, infragistics

I am using some controls from Infragistics2.Win.v10.3.Design . I know that this is not the latest version, but we haven't migrated to later versions yet.

The problem is that I have a windows forms control on which I have few UltraCalendarCombo controls. They don't scale and don't change their position when I change container control's AutoScaleMode to Font or to Dpi. What should I use to scale them? The font inside those controls scales well, actually. Should I resize them manually?

Or maybe the controls from this library are for .NET 1.1 FW, so that's why they don't support AutoScaleMode properties of their parent controls? Our application is compiled for .NET 4.0 FW.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with a UserControl and didn't reproduce the behavior.  If your control that you have created derives from ContainerControl, then you should get this behavior automatically in .NET 2.0 or later.  See [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: What verson of Infragistics controls did you test?

Comment: I tested this with 2012 Volume 2.